# checking for equality

Tags: r, subset

i want to check equality of a dataset. the data set is looking like this

```
Equips <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,7,8)
Notifs <- c(10,10,20,55,63,67,71,73,73,73,81,81,83,32,32,32,32,
47,48,45,45,45,51,51,55,56,69,65,88)
Comps <- c("Motor","Ventil","Motor","Gehäuse","Ventil","Motor","Steuerung","Motor",
"Ventil","Gehäuse","Gehäuse","Ventil","Motor","Schraube","Motor","Festplatte",
"Heizgerät","Motor","Schraube","Schraube","Lichtmaschine","Bremse","Lichtmaschine",
"Schraube","Lichtmaschine","Lichtmaschine","Motor","Ventil","Schraube")
rank <- c(1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,1,1,1,1,2,3,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,1,1,1)

df <- data.frame(Equips,Notifs,Comps,rank)
```

The data frame should be read line by line.

My problem is the following: 
I have a very big data set, and i want to take a look if the Comps in one Equips are the same in all ranks.

To specify: Equips 1 has got rank 1 and 2 i want to compare if there is a component listed in rank 1 and rank 2 ( in this example: YES)

Equips 2 hast got 3 ranks and here is, as well, no Comps which is listed in the first, second and third rank.

Equips 5 hast got 4 ranks and yes here is a Comps which is in every rank: namely "Lichtmaschine".

So what is my desired output? 
It would be enough, if i got an output, with the number of Equips, and with TRUE or FALSE(like summary command)

TRUE should be the output if there is a Comps which is listed in every rank (within one Equips)

There are also some notes: the dataset is very big so i need an automize version AND if it's possible, just with the standard R programm without any packages.

A really big Thanks for your effort.

Charly

Comment: I don't understand "*Equips 1 has got rank 1 and 2 i want to compare if there is a component list up in rank 1 and rank 2 ( in this example: No)*". `Motor` is present in both ranks of `Equips` `1`.

Comment: I think "list up" is supposed to mean "listed"...

Comment: @adibender The answer should be "yes" in this case (not "no").

Comment: For every unique value under the column 'Equips', he wants to check if any name under 'Comps' is associated with every 'rank'.

Comment: Sorry, but I think Sven is right : For `Equips 1`, the `Motor` comps is listed in both ranks...

Comment: Yes, you are right... Sorry for the mistake... of course answer 1 is right!!  sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer which uses the `plyr`package :

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(Equips), function(d) {
  nb.comps <- length(unique(d$rank))
  tab <- table(d$rank, d$Comps) > 0
  tab <- margin.table(tab, 2)
  return(sum(tab>=nb.comps)>0)
})
```

Which gives :

```
  Equips    V1
1      1  TRUE
2      2 FALSE
3      3 FALSE
4      4 FALSE
5      5  TRUE
```

If you really don't want to use `plyr`, you can use the `by` function :

```
by(df, df$Equips, function(d) {
  nb.comps <- length(unique(d$rank))
  tab <- table(d$rank, d$Comps) > 0
  tab <- margin.table(tab, 2)
  return(sum(tab>=nb.comps)>0)
})

df$Equips: 1
[1] TRUE
-------------------------------------------------------- 
df$Equips: 2
[1] FALSE
-------------------------------------------------------- 
df$Equips: 3
[1] FALSE
-------------------------------------------------------- 
df$Equips: 4
[1] FALSE
-------------------------------------------------------- 
df$Equips: 5
[1] TRUE
```

If you want to summarize the result you can do something like this :

```
result <- by(df, df$Equips, function(d) {
  nb.comps <- length(unique(d$Comps))
  tab <- table(d$rank, d$Comps) > 0
  tab <- margin.table(tab, 2)
  return(sum(tab>=nb.comps)>0)
})


data.frame(nb.equips=dim(result), nb.matched=sum(result))
```

Which gives :

```
  nb.equips nb.matched
1         5          2
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but like i told the data set is very big is there any possibilzy, to summarize this results like: 5000x TRUE 25000x FALSE or something like this?

Comment: Great answer, but 1 should be false.

Comment: @NathanG I don't think so... `Motor` is listed in both ranks, no ?

Comment: juba, you are right... just Equips 5 is correct... but like i ask is there any possibility to summarize this result? because i have more than 70.000 Equips?   Thanks

Comment: @Charly This should be fairly easy once you get the results in my answer. Hint : use `dim` and `sum` to get the number of `Equips` and the number of `TRUE` values.

Comment: Also by using your second code? (by) i am not be able to do it at the moment ... This question i am so long after and at the moment i am more than confused... Thank you

Comment: Yes, I've added it to my answer.

Comment: If the answer solved your question, it is best to check the green mark in order to indicate it to other users.

Comment: ok but there is a point which should alo be cleared please.   In my data set, the biggest part of it are just having one rank in one Equip.   So they are not comparable. how can i "remove" them from the calculation? because at the moment the output is wrong

Comment: Please open a new question, as it was not stated in your original one.

Comment: I edited in the question above are you able to answer it? if you took it in R you will know what i mean