# conditional query with few vectors

Tags: r, compare

short question.. with following example data:

```
Equips <- c(1000829,1000829,1000829,1000829,10002244,10002244,
10002244,10002244,10002244,10002244)
Notifs <-     c(306989814,306991263,306991263,306991263,306749278,306749278,
306749278,306749278,306854440,306868916)
Comps <- c("Ignition and Flame Detection","Ignition and Flame Detection","Control Box",
"Ignition and Flame Detection","Service Boiler!!!","CH Components Passive",
"Ignition and  Flame Detection","not grouped in WCC",
"Electrical Components","Flue Duct")
rank <- c(1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,3)
df <- data.frame(Equips,Notifs,Comps,rank)
```

Equip is like a number for a machine, so there are 2 machines, Notifs are a number for visits => rank show the number of visit for the machine.
Comps are Components which get repaired. I want to take a look if there are Components, which were repaired in every visit of this machine.

For example by machine 1, Ignition and Flame Detection was in rank 1 and rank 2 repaired, so i want to have an output TRUE,
machine 2 was visited 3 times, but there is no component which was repaired in rank1,2 and 3 so the output should be FALSE. ( the original dataset, has Equips visited up to 10 times!!)

I had a similar question and had this code.

but it is not working. Maybe you can get a hind with it:

```
 result <- by(df, df$Equips, function(d) {
    nb.comps <- length(unique(df$Comps))
    tab <- table(df$rank, df$Comps) > 0
    tab <- margin.table(tab, 2)
    return(sum(tab>=nb.comps)>0)
  })

data.frame(nb.equips=dim(result), nb.matched=sum(result))
```

I really want something like this, because i have no opportunity to install any packages, and because of the size of  the data set, i really need an overall view like the last code.
If you have any questions please ask.

Comment: what do you mean you have no opportunity to install any packages? you require a base solution?

Comment: Yes I require a basic solution ... sorry for the misunderstanding....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this ? The problem in your code is that you replaced `d` by `df` inside the function. It seems to me that my answer was correct in [your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769346/checking-for-equality)...

```
result <- by(df, df$Equips, function(d) {
    nb.comps <- length(unique(d$Comps))
    tab <- table(d$rank, d$Comps) > 0
    tab <- margin.table(tab, 2)
    return(sum(tab>=nb.comps)>0)
  })
```

Which gives :

```
R> result
df$Equips: 1000829
[1] TRUE
-------------------------------------------------------- 
df$Equips: 10002244
[1] FALSE
R> data.frame(nb.equips=dim(result), nb.matched=sum(result))
  nb.equips nb.matched
1         2          1
```

Comment: Yes Sir, i really do not know what i have done ?!